# How to call python user-defined function in main( )?

Tags: python, function

I create some functions and how to call them in main( )? It throws NameError: name 'list_A' is not defined

```
def main():
    
    output_item_statistics(list_A, list_B, fh_out)




def output_item_statistics(list_A, list_B, fh_out):

    number = 0
    for a, b in zip(list_A, list_B):
        number = number + 1
        item_number = _get_item_number(list_A)
        n_counts = _get_item_counts('N', list_B)
        e_counts = _get_item_counts('E', list_B)
        t_counts = _get_item_counts('T', list_B)
        

        fh_out.write("{0} {1} {2} {3} \n".format(number, item_number, n_counts, e_counts,t_counts)
```

Comment: Where do you define the functions, and when? Is the code in one file, or do you `import`, and if so, how? Show your full code. Also, is the NameError for the function, or for the parameters? My guess would be the latter.

Comment: Are you defining these functions in another file?
Does main actually have the variables list_a, list_b and fh_out within reach in terms of scope?

Comment: Yes, it shows NameError: name 'list_A' is not defined.

Comment: Sorry that I'm a beginner. All of the defined functions and main( ) are in the same python file. How to call a function in def main( )?

Answer (score 0):

It feels like your files are not in the same directory. Here's a sample:

```
Main Folder
    → Python File `main()`
    → Folder
        → Second File `output_item_statistics)`
```

If there's such a case in your system then try importing the folder:

```
import folder_name.file_name as file_name
```

Then you need to call the function with:

```
file_name.output_item_statistics
```

If your directory is same but the function is in another file then simply import the file:

```
import file_name
```

Or:

```
from file_name import * # To import all the functions
```